# How can i fix this keyboard shortcut error?

Tags: html, atom-editor

This error is in atom editor. When I press Ctrl-O key to open file, the file selection window is normally worked. But if i select the html file, the file doesn't appear.(the file selection window is ignored.)
How can i fix this keyboard shortcut error? help :(
ps. I'm using the Windows operating system

Comment: why do you believe that the problem is with the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Then why this problem exists? I don't know well..

Answer (score 0):

Atom ships with the [keybinding-resolver](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) core package. You can toggle its panel from the command palette running *Key Binding Resolver: Toggle*. With the panel open, press the troubled shortcut and it should reveal the package causing a conflict.

**Example:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can go through *all* keybindings listed under *Settings > Keybindings*.